# Is it correct to nominalise the adjective "favourite"?

Tags: nouns, nominalization

Following this first question: "What are your favourite novels?", should I ask: "Why are they your favourites?" using "favourite" as a noun, or "Why are they your favourite?" or "Why are they your favourite ones", using "favourite" as an adjective?

Comment: Favourite (noun) a thing that someone likes best or enjoys most. Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: What does your preferred dictionary say?

Answer (score 2):

"Favourite" -- "favorite" here in America -- can be used as either a noun or an adjective.

The catch to using "favorite" as a noun is that you have to establish context. If someone began a conversation by saying, "What is your favorite?", the obvious response would be, "My favorite what?" But once the context is established, repeating the subject is superfluous. Like if someone says, "My favorite actress is Florence Henderson. Who is your favorite?", well, obviously they mean your favorite actress.